# IME not loading... initially

Tags: 16.10, input-method, fcitx

I'm using 16.10; I just switched my IME system from IBus to fcitx.  After a restart, fcitx doesn't load--I have to log out and back in to get it to load.  After a fresh restart, im-config outputs this:

```
Current configuration for the input method:
 * Active configuration: fcitx (normally missing)
 * Normal automatic choice: ibus (normally ibus or fcitx or uim)
 * Override rule: zh_CN,fcitx:zh_TW,fcitx:zh_HK,fcitx:zh_SG,fcitx:ja_JP,fcitx:ko_KR,fcitx:vi_VN,fcitx
 * Current override choice:  (en_US)
 * Current automatic choice: ibus
 * Number of valid choices: 3 (normally 1)
The override rule is defined in /etc/default/im-config.
The configuration set by im-config is activated by re-starting X.
Explicit selection is not required to enable the automatic configuration if the active one is default/auto/cjkv/missing.
  Available input methods: ibus fcitx xim
Unless you really need them all, please make sure to install only one input method tool.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

```
$ cat .xinputrc 
# im-config(8) generated on Tue, 25 Apr 2017 10:29:12 -0400
run_im fcitx
# im-config signature: 6ede3b67d21b39da01fe58c378a3cd0e  -
```

---

I dig some digging in `var/log/syslog`.

Fresh restart:

```
Apr 25 10:59:11 ---- systemd[2078]: Started Launch and configure input method.
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: =========================
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: FCITX 4.2.9.1 -- Get Signal No.: 15
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: Date: try "date -d @1493132352" if you are using GNU date ***
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: ProcessID: 2582
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/bin/fcitx(+0x14d6)[0x562efd21e4d6]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x35860)[0x7f864b186860]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__open64+0x10)[0x7f864b248a50]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_file_open+0x23)[0x7f864b1cca93]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_file_fopen+0x1d5)[0x7f864b1ccd55]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ef84)[0x7f864b1bff84]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfcitx-config.so.4(FcitxXDGGetFile+0x1a1)[0x7f864b9586e1]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfcitx-config.so.4(FcitxXDGGetFileWithPrefix+0x49)[0x7f864b958fc9]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfcitx-core.so.0(FcitxGlobalConfigLoad+0x14c)[0x7f864bb6bd8c]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfcitx-core.so.0(+0x8391)[0x7f864bb69391]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfcitx-core.so.0(FcitxInstanceRun+0x210)[0x7f864bb6a0b0]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/bin/fcitx(+0xfbc)[0x562efd21dfbc]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f864b1713f1]
Apr 25 10:59:12 ---- sh[2529]: /usr/bin/fcitx(_start+0x2a)[0x562efd21e03a]
```

After login:

```
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- systemd[5336]: Started Launch and configure input method.
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-hangul.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chewing.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-kimpanel-ui.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-classic-ui.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-quickphrase.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-table.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin-enhance.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-cloudpinyin.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-sunpinyin.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-mozc.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-keyboard.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-notificationitem.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-ipc.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-remote-module.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-x11.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xim.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-unicode.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-clipboard.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkbdbus.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-dbus.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-freedesktop-notify.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-imselector.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chttrans.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkb.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-spell.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-lua.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: (INFO-5794 /build/fcitx-GAANyG/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-vk.conf
Apr 25 10:54:05 ---- sh[5772]: Unable to create /home/matt/.dbus/session-bus
```

Comment: How did you determine it didn't load? Which Ubuntu flavor are you on?

Comment: Standard Ubuntu; no keyboard icon.  Also, no fcitx under ps -aux

Comment: What does the command `env | grep -E '_IM|XMOD'` output?

Comment: `$ env | grep -E '_IM|XMOD'`
`CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim`
`QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx`
`XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx`
`QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx`
`GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx`

Comment: Updated info from log

Comment: Odd. Is autologin enabled? Does it make a difference if you disable it and always log in via the greeter? Is your system fully updated? `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`